# When do I use the state complement?

Tags: grammar

Recently I have been confused about when I am to use the state complement. For example, if I want to say "In general I read the messages quickly", which sentence should I write?

1. 我一般很快地看留言
2. 我一般看留言看得很快

Maybe both are right? But somehow the two sentences don't sound the same to me.

Comment: １） 很快(地) in pre-verbal position functions as adverbial adjunct (状语）
２）很快 in post-verbal position functions as complement (补语, requiring 得）（cf。＂外国人实用汉语语法＂程度补语  宾语的位置 （１）要是动词谓语后面同时带宾语和程度补语，一定要重复动词，程度补语要放在重复的动词后边，助词＂得＂则要放在重复的动词和程度补语之中。（２）如果不重复动词，就要把宾语放在动词谓语或者主语前边。
i。e。besides ２）above 我一般留言看得很快 and 留言我一般看得很快 are also possible with 很快 as complement of degree

Comment: Both are right. #1 is plain, #2 focuses on 'quick'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chinese the basic syntactic structure is:

> 主语, Subject + (状语, Adverb) + 动词, Verb + (补语, Complements)

So, from this structure we can see that the **adverb** comes *before* the verb and the **complement** slot *follows* the verb.

Whatever precedes the verb modifies its meaning. So, since the adverb comes before the predicate, it behaves like a *determinant*. 很快(地) in your first sentence adds more information to the main action, 看.

On the other hand, whatever follows the verb represents the results of the predicate, it *completes* the meaning of the verb and that's why this place is reserved for complements. The degree complement, or 程度补语, it's a very special complement that specifies the qualities of the action. You could think about it as *picture* of the predicate.

Thus, both your sentences are correct from a grammatical point of view. They also mean the exactly same thing. The difference between the two consist in the focus.
In the first sentence the predicate (看) is the most important element. In the second instead the degree of the action (得很快) receives the focus.

> 我一般很快地看留言。
>   In general I **read** messages. *How* do I read them? *Quickly*.
>   
>   我一般看留言看得很快。
>   In general I **read** messages and my action has the *result* to be *quick*.

Answer (score -1):

both are fine. they are expressing the same thing